# Rails 3 i18n "translate" method translates correctly but shows "translation missing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm running Rails 3.0.9

I have this:

```
<%= t time_ago_in_words(i.created_at) %>
```

And it prints:

```
<span title="translation missing: pt-BR.2 minutos" class="translation_missing">2 Minutos</span>
```

The translations is **working** but the *"translation missing"* keeps showing up. Does anybody know why?

I'm using the rails-i18n pt-BR.yml from here: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/pt-BR.yml

And in my application.rb:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = "pt-BR"
```

Even if I remove the line above from aplication.rb the "translation missing" keeps showing up!

It is making crazy. =[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation is already being handled by the `time_ago_in_words` helper, returning "2 minutos". You don't need to pass the result back to the `t` method again.  When you call `t` on the already translated string, i18n is treating it as a key and trying to look it up again.

Comment: How didn't I notice that?? haha. Thanks buddy!